# Find an efficient algorithm to calculate $\sin(x) $

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods

Suggest an efficient algorithm to determine the value of the
function $ \sin(x) $ for $ x \in [-4\pi, 4\pi] $.

You can use only Taylor series and $ +, -, *, /$.

I know, that $$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n + 1)!}$$
but I can't find an efficient algorithm.

Thank for your help.

Comment: First reduce the range to $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Hint: Use range reduction to $[-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]$ and use the series for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Comment: Series should start at $n=0$ and $(-1)^n$ is missing.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97560/numerically-efficient-approximation-of-coss and code at http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_sin.c .

Comment: @Ihf but how I can reduce the range to $ [0, \pi/2] $ ? How to make the transformation Taylor series $ \sin(x) $ - it's the only difficulty in this task ?

Comment: @user99324, see the trigonometric circle.

Comment: @Ihf Hmm, still I don't see nothing, maybe you've one more hint ? Because I can't write  this formally.

Comment: @Ihf I can't use http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_sin.c because after  write algorithm, I have to compare both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The coefficients of the series are related to one another by the simple relation:

$$
t_{n+1}=\frac{x^{2(n+1)+1}}{(2(n+1)+1)!}=\frac{x^2}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=
\frac{x^2}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}t_n
$$

(Here $t_n$ represents the coefficient of $x^{2n+1}$, multiplied by $x^{2n+1}$.  So $\sin x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty t_n$.)

This means that you don't need to work out each coefficient separately: once you've worked out $t_n$, you've done most of the work you need to do to work out $t_{n+1}$.

The other thing you'll need to do is to work out how many terms of the series you'll need to ge a good enough approximation on $[-4\pi,4\pi]$.